# Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' does not have an implementation

Tags: methods, typeloadexception

I have a problem and I would really appreciate it if you could help me
I want to build some rest APIs using the .NET framework. When I want to make a GET request to retrieve all the records from the database table, it gives me the following error. This error also gives me the POST request.
Thank you very much!

System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions.MySQLServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkMySQL(IServiceCollection services)
at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.MySQLOptionsExtension.ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices(IDbContextOptions options, ServiceCollection services)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.g__BuildServiceProvider|4_1(IDbContextOptions _, ValueTuple`2 arguments) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c.<GetOrAdd>b__4_0(IDbContextOptions contextOptions, ValueTuple`2 tuples)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd[TArg](TKey key, Func`3 valueFactory, TArg factoryArgument)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
at CRUD_operation.Model.UniversitateContext..ctor(DbContextOptions`1 options) in /home/david/CRUD operation/Model/UniversitateContext.cs:line 14
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
at System.Reflection.ConstructorInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)